# Programmatically initialize ViewController

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, initialization

I am trying to initialise a `UIViewController` in my Swift application but I am facing a problem to which I cannot find any definitive answer.

I would like to call this from a FlowCoordinator to initialise the controller, but my initialiser requires a NSCoder object due to the required init?(coder: NSCoder) function.

```swift
MyAwesomeController()
```

Is there a way to initialise differently the controller, without the need to pass the `NSCoder` object?

If there is not, how can I create such an object in a way to avoid the following exception:

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -decodeObjectForKey: cannot
>   be sent to an abstract object of class NSCoder: Create a concrete
>   instance!'

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: You can create an additional initializer.

Comment: You might want to read this: http://www.programmingios.net/dont-make-a-new-instance-by-mistake-2/

Comment: Thank you @matt, you solved my problem, I didn't get before that I was creating a new controller, not the one I had already linked to the storyboard.

Comment: You are welcome! Those articles are meant to help with common problems like this. So I'm very happy if I helped you "get" this concept.

Answer (score 11):

Use something like this, I included a property also as a demo:

```
class MyAwesomeViewController: UIViewController {
    let someInt: Int

    init(someInt: Int) {
        self.someInt = someInt

        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("Storyboard are a pain")
    }
}
```

I like creating everything programmatically.

Comment: I tried this method but it launches the fatalError because I am not providing the NSCoder object when I create the Controller in the FlowCoordinator. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Since UIViewController inherits feom UIResponder, and UIResponder inherits from NSObject, it has empty initializer like init().
So you can just call MyAwesomeController() and it works without any errors.
If there is any the error is somewhere else like an outlet in storyboard.